# Solve_ivp() breaks down on certain calculations after a while

Tags: python, solver

I'm doing some simulations using the Social Force Model in which a bunch of forces are calculated that are acting upon each person. The model seems to be working fine up to a certain point, visible around 20s into the gif. It looks as though the model completely stop calculating forces on a select few of pedestrians and I was wondering why. I do have a part of the code that uses the "break" function to stop calculating forces, but this should only be triggered once they have reached a x-position of larger than 34. The code basically tells them to first move towards the first green line in the doorway and once they have reached that, they should move to the second one to the right at x=35. Has anyone experienced similar issues with the solve_ivp function, or knows some handy methods to debug. I find it hard to debug, because a lot of this is happening inside the solver.

Here's some parts of the code that are relevant, first block shows the forces calculation

```
    # create empty forces matrices
    # can i use the functions to create the force matrices and then solve them?
    fd = np.zeros([N,2])       # all fid are used for driving effect
    fi = np.zeros([N,2])       # all fir are used for interaction effect
    fi1 = np.zeros([N,2])
    fi2 = np.zeros([N,2])
    fb = np.zeros([N,2])       # all fiw are used for boundary effect
    fb1 = np.zeros([N,2])
    fb2 = np.zeros([N,2])
    
    # loop for computing forces over all pedestrians, every iteration is a different pedestrian
    
                
    for i in range(N):
        
        # checkpoint system
        if p[i].pos[0][0] >= (destination[-1][0][0]-1):
            break
        
        check_box = checkpoint_box(p[i].destination[0], p[i].destination[1])

        if checkpoint_reached(p[i].pos[0], check_box):
            p[i].index += 1
            p[i].destination = destination[p[i].index]
        
        # driving effect    
        fd[i] = driving_effect(p[i].mass, p[i].destination, p[i].pos, p[i].desired_velocity, p[i].velocity, t_relax)
        
        # interaction effect
        for j in range(N):
            if i != j:
                fit, fit1, fit2 = interaction_effect(p[i].pos, p[j].pos, p[i].radius, p[j].radius, p[i].velocity, p[j].velocity)
                fi[i,:] += fit
                fi1[i,:] += fit1
                fi2[i,:] += fit2
        # boundary effect     
        fb[i,:], fb1[i,:], fb2[i,:] = boundary_effect(p[i].pos, p[i].radius, p[i].velocity)
        

    F = fd + fi + fi1 + fi2 + fb + fb1 + fb2
    
    ## sum of all forces
    
    return F
```

The function that is called upon by the solve_ivp() function:

```
    def motion(t, X):
        
        all_forces = Forces(X)
    
        for i in range(N):
            dX[i*MMM] = X[i*MMM+2]
            dX[i*MMM+1] = X[i*MMM+3]
            dX[i*MMM+2] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,0]
            dX[i*MMM+3] = (1/p[i].mass)*all_forces[i,1]            
        return dX
    
    # start solver
    
    #print("starting solver...")
    sol = solve_ivp(motion, t_span, x_initial, method='RK23',t_eval=t)
```

[image: evacuation simulation]